# How to get dependencies for spring bean?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

I am trying with following code:

```
ConfigurableListableBeanFactory factory = ((AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext) applicationContext)
            .getBeanFactory();
factory.getDependenciesForBean(beanName)
```

But I am facing this error.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext cannot be cast to org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext
```

Please provide your valuable input,in case you had faced this problem,what way shall I proceed?

Comment: Why are you trying to cast the application context bean you have to an `AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext` when your exception message is clearly saying that you can't cast your `GenericApplicationContext` to the `AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext`. My question is why are you trying to do that?

Comment: In order to get a refreshed applicationcontext,so that I can get proper dependent beans

Comment: Casting your application context to a different type of object isn't going to refresh it.....

Answer (score 2):

this works

```
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("context.xml");
ConfigurableListableBeanFactory bf = ctx.getBeanFactory();
bf.getDependenciesForBean(beanName)
```